# Editing .ini file in InstallShield self extracting exe

Tags: installshield, edit, self-extracting

I have a self-extracting exe created using InstallShield 2010. I need to modify the setup.ini file in it, without fully unpacking the installer. I downloaded the internal_setupini.exe utility from http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q107253. This file is officially supported for version 2009.

When I try to run the command it gives me 'Could not open <>.exe" error. Is this utility not supported for 2010?

My primary objective is to personalize the setup file for each of my user, so that user specific information is embedded within this setup. This is the reason why I want to open up the installer and write items into the ini. Is there any alternate(better) way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Would it make sense to just build the install with the unique data over and over for each customer? I once knew a company back in the 90's that did this.  A customer would fax their signature to them on an order form then they would get an email with the download location of the install containing their signature. ( it was called signaturemail.com as I recall )

Comment: Though I would prefer altering the .ini, rebuilding it would also work. How can I trigger rebuild from c# code? Is it even possible to do that?